# When assigning values to a UserForm from an array how do I switch between box types..."Caption" and "Value"

Tags: arrays, vba, controls, userform

eg A "Label" the value is stored in "Caption" whilst a Textboxes uses "Value" Please...

...but elegantly

I know I could use and "if then" statement ... but I see it getting messy pretty quick.

```
Dim propValue(2, 2) As String
    propValue(0, 1) = "SomeInfo"
    propValue(1, 1) = "lblReference"
    propValue(2, 1) = "Caption"
    propValue(0, 2) = "MoreInfo"
    propValue(1, 2) = "tboxReference"
    propValue(2, 2) = "Value"

Dim element As Integer
For element = 1 To 2
   UserForm1.Controls(propValue(1, element)).propValue(2, element) = propValue(0, element)
Next element
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You cannot use a string as an `Object` property, as you try. You should match somehow the used string with the type of the used control. I will try showing an example...

Comment: You can also use the string you initially tried ("Caption" and "Value"). I changed them only to have a solution to check if there are not inconsistences in your way of loading the array. I mean, you can preliminary check that in the next way: `If TypeName(ctrl) = propValue(0, element) Then` validate somehow the operation your code tries, or rise in error in case of a problematic choice...

Answer (score 1):

As I tried saying in my comment, it is not possible to use a string (extracted from an array or not) as an `Object Property`. The next code store a string defining the control  type and use it in the following way:

```
Sub testModifFormControlsProperties()
   Dim propValue(2, 2) As String
    propValue(0, 1) = "SomeInfo": propValue(1, 1) = "lblReference"
    propValue(2, 1) = "Label"    'store the control type as String
    
    propValue(0, 2) = "MoreInfo": propValue(1, 2) = "tboxReference"
    propValue(2, 2) = "TextBox" 'store the control type as String
    
    Dim element As Integer, ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For element = 1 To 2
        Set ctrl = UserForm1.Controls(propValue(1, element)) 'to make a compact code
        Select Case propValue(2, element)
            Case "TextBox": ctrl.Text = propValue(0, element)
            Case "Label": ctrl.Caption = propValue(0, element)
        End Select
    Next element
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers knowing its not possible is just the medicine I need .... at least I can move on.  The case option will have to be elgant enougth :)

Comment: @Floggedhorse You can also use the strings you initially tried ("Caption" and "Value"). I changed them only to have a solution of checking if there are not inconsistences in your way of loading the array. I mean, you can preliminary check that in the next way: `If TypeName(ctrl) = propValue(0, element) Then` validate somehow the operation your code tries, or rise in error in case of a problematic choices...

Answer (score 1):

For the additional price of a very simple data object, the following is an approach that avoids using a 2-d `Array`.  You could use a `Collection` or an `Array` with this implementation.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub InitTextBoxesAndLabels()
        
    Dim propValue(1) As Variant
    Set propValue(0) = CreateTextBoxOrLabel("Label1", "MoreInfo", True)
    Set propValue(1) = CreateTextBoxOrLabel("TextBox1", "SomeInfo", False)

    Dim dElement As TextBoxOrLabel
    
    Dim element As Long
    For element = 0 To 1
        Set dElement = propValue(element)
        If dElement.IsLabel Then
            UserForm1.Controls(dElement.ControlName).Caption = dElement.Content
        Else
            UserForm1.Controls(dElement.ControlName).Value = dElement.Content
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Function CreateTextBoxOrLabel(ByVal pControlName As String, _
    pContent As String, pIsLabel As Boolean) As TextBoxOrLabel
    
    Set CreateTextBoxOrLabel = New TextBoxOrLabel
    
    With CreateTextBoxOrLabel
        .ControlName = pControlName
        .Content = pContent
        .IsLabel = pIsLabel
    End With

End Function
```

*TextBoxOrLabel data object*

```
Option Explicit

Public IsLabel As Boolean
Public Content As String
Public ControlName As String
```